# Nativescript RadCalendar with firebase realtime database

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to retrive list of events and show it on My RadCalender in Native script the firebase method retrieve the data and I can print the results in the console , but when I am trying to add the data on the RadCalendar I cant see it , also I dont see any errors !! can help please

Also is the onPageLoad is the best place to load these events in the calendar ?

this is the code

## Firebase query :

```
public queryValues(): Array<any> {
    var eventsArray: Array<any> = new Array();
    var onQueryEvent = function (result) {
  
        if (!result.error) {
            console.info(result.value)
            eventsArray.push(result.value);
        }
    };

    firebase.query(
        onQueryEvent,
        "/events",
        {
            singleEvent: false,
            orderBy: {
                type: firebase.QueryOrderByType.CHILD,
                value: 'since'
            }
        }
    );
    
    return eventsArray;
}
```

## calendar view model

```
import { Observable } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable";
import * as  calendarModule from "nativescript-ui-calendar";
import { DBUtil } from "../services/dbutil"

export class CalenderViewModel extends Observable {
    private _dbUtil: DBUtil;
    private dbEvents: Array<EventData>;
    private _events: Array<any>;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this._dbUtil = new DBUtil();
        this.dbEvents = this._dbUtil.queryValues();
        this._events = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.dbEvents.length; i++) {
            var eventElement = JSON.parse(<any>this.dbEvents[i]);
            let date = new Date(eventElement.event.dateDate);
            let fullYear = date.getFullYear();
            let month = date.getMonth();
            let day = date.getDate();
           
            let startTimeHours = new Date(eventElement.event.startDateTime).getHours();
            let startTimeMinutes = new Date(eventElement.event.startDateTime).getMinutes();
            
            let endTimeHours = new Date(eventElement.event.endDateTime).getHours();
            let endTimeMinutes = new Date(eventElement.event.endDateTime).getMinutes();

            var startDate = new Date(fullYear,month,day,startTimeHours,startTimeMinutes);
            var endDate = new Date(fullYear,month,day,endTimeHours,endTimeMinutes);

            var event = new calendarModule.CalendarEvent(eventElement.event.title, startDate, endDate);
            this._events.push(event);
        }

    }


    get events():  Array<any> {
        return this._events;
    }
}

export class EventData {
    private title: string;
    private description: string;
    private dateDate: string;
    private endDateTime: number;
    private startDateTime: number;

    constructor(title: string, description: string,dateDate: string, startDateTime: number, endDateTime: number){
        this.title = title;
        this.description =description;
        this.dateDate =dateDate;
        this.startDateTime =startDateTime;
        this.endDateTime = endDateTime;
    }
}
```

## Calendar view

```
import { CalenderViewModel } from "./calendar-view-model";
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";
import * as frameNavigation from '../shared/navigation';
import { EventData } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable";
import { View } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";


export function pageLoaded(args) {
    let page = <Page>args.object;
    let clnViewModel = new CalenderViewModel();
    (<View>args.object).bindingContext = clnViewModel;
}
```

## calendar xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" xmlns:calendar="nativescript-ui-calendar" loaded="pageLoaded">
    <ActionBar title="D-shop" android.icon="res://icon" android.iconVisibility="always">
     <ActionItem tap="onAdd"
      ios.systemIcon="4" 
      android.systemIcon="ic_menu_add"
      ios.position="right"
      android.position="right" tap="onAddClicked">
      </ActionItem>
    </ActionBar>
    <calendar:RadCalendar id="myCalendar" eventSource="{{ events }}" viewMode="Day" />
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the change detection will never happen as `_events` is an simple property, it suppose to be a ObservableProperty, updated via `.set('propertyName', value)` method Or should use `ObservableProperty` decorator.

Second, just pushing / popping elements out of an Array won't update the calendar, you will have to replace the reference of the array by creating new one and inject new elements.

If you still have issues, please share a Playgorund sample where the issue can be reproduced.

**Edit:**

Here is a [Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=eiHg8a) that loads events array asynchronously (with a timeout), the events are populated in RadCalendar as expected.

Comment: I changed the _event to
        let _events: Array<calendarModule.CalendarEvent> = new Array<calendarModule.CalendarEvent>();

then I push 

Also I set the events value 

this.set("events", _events);

but still same issue :-(

Comment: Can u give sample for your second note ? @Manoj